# error downloading files in IE in Azure VM

Tags: azure

it's my first VM in Azure and getting an error when I am trying to download files from my copy.com service to run in the VM.
"your you current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded"

please advice,
thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That usually means that your internet options setting will not allow you to download files. Try this if you can. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10445481/2171266

If that doesn't work, I'm assuming you are using Windows Server (any version from 2012-2019), you can go to '**Server Manager**' click on '**Local Server**' and your '**IE Enhanced Security Configuration**' is probably '**On**'. Click on 'On' and turn it '**Off**'

Comment: The second option is the way to go. And this annoying to see Microsoft still have IE as default browser on VMs.

Answer (score 2):

Brandon Staley's solution didn't work for me today.  Had to add *.microsoft.com to trusted sites

Internet Options -> Security Tab -> Select Trusted Sites -> Sites Button -> add *.microsoft.com

Comment: This also did the job for me